Accessing the previous rows of the same calculating column in dax
I am creating a new calculated column called Final_Value in my calculated table called INDEX_1.
The condition is I have three columns called Kombi,JJJJ_MM, Value. Each kombi consists one row entry for each month starting from 12-2020, till 06-2024. The logic starts from December 2020. For that month the Final_Value is the same as Value. From the next month, if the value is 50% more than the Previous month's Final_Value and the difference is greater than 1000,then change the current value to 1.5*Final_Value of last month.
if the value is 50% less than the Previous month's Final_Value and the difference is less than -1000,then change the current value to 0.5*Final_Value of last month.
If the condition does not meet then keep the Current Value as Final_Value
I Tried the following code:
Final_Value = 

VAR kombirow=[Kombi]
VAR curr_val=[Value]
VAR month_row=[JJJJ_MM]

VAR Prev_Val= MAXX(
    FILTER(
        Index_1,
        [Kombi]==kombirow &&
        [JJJJ_MM]== EDATE(month_row,-1)
    ),
    [Final_Value]
)

VAR Difference= curr_val-Prev_Val
VAR Index_prev= Difference*100/Prev_Val

RETURN IF(
    [JJJJ_MM]==DATE(2020,12,1),
    curr_val,
    (
        IF(
            Difference<-1000 && Index_prev<-50,
            Prev_Val*0.5,
            (
                IF(
                    Difference>1000 && Index_prev>50,
                    Prev_Val*1.5,
                    curr_val
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

But I'm getting circular dependency error. If anyone have an alternate code, It would be of great help. Thanks in Advance.
Sample 1
Sample 2
In both the cases the Value Altered is the desired output

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

I have uploaded the output in sample images

2021/7/1 has the same value as previous month. Why the expected value increased?
